# How to set iReport page height dynamically when it generate

Tags: java, dynamic, height, report, ireport

i'm new for iReport. i'm building a point of sale system using java. to print the receipt i used the irepot. my problem is when i'm generate a report report height is not get reduce or increase dynamically.

for ex : when there are 2 rows in the report report height must be reduce. if there the 50 rows in the report, report height must be increase dynamically.

How can i do that....

Comment: yep!!!!! i got the way how to do that 

set the prosperity   ignore **pagination =true** in the report

Regards..

Answer (score 2):

select report > Properties > Ignore pagination = true

```
<jasperReport 
 xmlns=....
 ...
 ...
 isIgnorePagination="true" 
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put the fields in detail band. This is an basic tutorial: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/ireportwebsite/IR%20Website/ir_design_a_report.html

Regards

Comment: yep!!!!! i got the way how to do that 

set the prosperity   ignore **pagination =true** in the report

Regards..